# iOS - AdobeCreativeSDK Frameworks

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, adobecreativesdk

**Configuring `Xcode` For Using Static `AdobeCreativeSDK Frameworks`**.

[image: **Configuring Xcode For Using Static <code>AdobeCreativeSDK Frameworks</code>**. I get below error]

OR

**Configuring Xcode For Using Dynamic `AdobeCreativeSDK Frameworks`**

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AdobeCreativeSDKCore.framework/AdobeCreativeSDKCore
  Referenced from: /Users/Planetx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A24ABE69-60B0-4EFE-B86D-8D0D9982F920/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B6BE5CBD-4E1F-4694-8CD9-423D57898DD8/InstaFeed.app/InstaFeed
  Reason: image not found

Do you have any idea how I can solve this error ?